# Running Django test tries to import module that was deleted

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-unittest

I have a Django project that I am trying to test. It had an app named 'people' that I have replaced with another app 'participant'. I have changed all of the settings needed, but why I run`python manage.py test`, it won't run the tests because it `can't import people`, because I deleted it.

Is there something I can delete or reset to remove all of the memory of previous test runs? Everything else works fine.

Comment: try removing all the `pyc` files then try running the tests again

Comment: That didn't do it @ruddra

Comment: It's possible that you still have references to people app in your import statements. I'd do a project-wide search for "people" to see if there are any references left

Comment: This is bad: I forgot to change my Bash alias for the test set I was running. It was still set to test people. Thanks @OzgurAkcali